# Why does my control (component) disappear when I set the 'control name' to "test-controlenummer" in Orbeon Form Builder?

Tags: orbeon

I'm building a form in the Orbeon Form Builder. The simplest way to recreate this problem is as follows:

1. Put a control on the form.
2. Give it any label, it does not matter.
3. Go to 'control details'.
4. Change the 'Control Name' to 'test-controlenummer'.
5. Confirm with the 'apply' button.
6. See the control itself disappear

Notice that the question mark of the help feature does not disappear, nor do the delete and validation options once you hover over the formerly-visible-component. The grid cell also acts as if it was occupied. The control simply does not show and some of the changes to the name and/or validation options result in XPath expression errors.

I have taken a quick look at the underlying xml code, however at first glance I did not find anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It disappears because of a bug in Orbeon Forms 3.9 when control names contain a dash. Like you said, there is nothing wrong with the markup Form Builder generates, but it then incorrectly just doesn't expect a dash to be present in the control name.

- This bug has been fixed in the latest code, so it won't be present in the next release.
- If you are using [Orbeon Forms PE](http://www.orbeon.com/support-services/professional), I recommend you contact Orbeon to see if you can get a patch for this (either through Basecamp if you already have a support account setup, or by email, info AT orbeon.com).
- If you are using Orbeon Forms CE, for now, you can work around this issue by avoiding dashes in the names of your controls.